# How to dehydrate a Django model fieldname?

Tags: python, django, django-models, tastypie

I have a Django model as follows:

```
class History(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'CREATE'),
        (0, 'EDIT'),
        (2, 'DELETE'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+')
    cp = models.ForeignKey('cp', related_name="history")
    field_name = models.CharField(max_length=192, null=False)
    old_value = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    new_value = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    type = models.IntegerField(default=0, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and resources(tastypie),

```
class HistoryResource(ModelResource):
    Id = fields.IntegerField('cp__id', null=True)
    username = fields.CharField('user__username', null=True)
    type_name = fields.CharField(attribute='type_name', null=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = History.objects.all()

        def dehydrate_field_name(self, bundle):
            if bundle.data['field_name'] == 'category_a':
                return bundle.data['field_name'] = 'function'

        fields = ['id', 'type_name', 'Id', 'username', 'field_name', 'old_value',
                  'new_value', 'type', 'date_created']
        allowed_methods = ['get']
```

In my dehydrate I want to convert my field_name value to functional if the value of field_name is category_a. But Its not working as expected. What's wrong here?Am very new to tastypie/resources.

Comment: What does _not working as expected_ means? What output do you get?

Comment: It didn't returned nothing Railslide. Expected value: is `function`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have a custom dehydration you need to extend the `dehydrate` method, which means that your method should either be called `dehydrate` or called by the `dehydrate` method.

Then, in your method you should return the whole bundle, not only the changed key-value pair.

```
def dehydrate(self, bundle):
    if bundle.data['field_name'] == 'category_a':
        bundle.data['field_name'] = 'function'
    return bundle
```

See tastypie docs http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html?highlight=dehydrate#Resource.dehydrate

Comment: Thanks railslide. Lemme give a try. Thanks a lot :)